# What does "unconnected:sendto() " return value mean?

Tags: lua, udp, return-value, luasocket

The LuaSocket documentation says:

> `unconnected:sendto(datagram, ip, port)`
>
> If successful, the method returns 1. In case of error, the method
>   returns nil followed by an error message.

But I get a value of `4`. What does return value of `4` means?

My code is here:

```
local socket = require("socket")

udp = socket.udp()
udp:setsockname("*", 8080)

local msg = "Test"

m=assert(udp:sendto( msg, "228.192.1.1", 8080))
print(m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closely at [the source](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/src/udp.c#L172-L203) inside `udp.c` for `sendo` method

```
static int meth_sendto(lua_State *L) {
    p_udp udp = (p_udp) auxiliar_checkclass(L, "udp{unconnected}", 1);
    size_t count, sent = 0;
    const char *data = luaL_checklstring(L, 2, &count);
    const char *ip = luaL_checkstring(L, 3);
    const char *port = luaL_checkstring(L, 4);
    p_timeout tm = &udp->tm;
    int err;
    struct addrinfo aihint;
    struct addrinfo *ai;
    memset(&aihint, 0, sizeof(aihint));
    aihint.ai_family = udp->family;
    aihint.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    aihint.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST | AI_NUMERICSERV;
    err = getaddrinfo(ip, port, &aihint, &ai);
    if (err) {
        lua_pushnil(L);
        lua_pushstring(L, gai_strerror(err));
        return 2;
    }
    timeout_markstart(tm);
    err = socket_sendto(&udp->sock, data, count, &sent, ai->ai_addr,
        (socklen_t) ai->ai_addrlen, tm);
    freeaddrinfo(ai);
    if (err != IO_DONE) {
        lua_pushnil(L);
        lua_pushstring(L, udp_strerror(err));
        return 2;
    }
    lua_pushnumber(L, (lua_Number) sent);
    return 1;
}
```

Basically, the documentation's "*returns 1*" statement is wrong. The `return 1` statement in the code means that the actual function returns one value, which is actually pushed into the stack:

```
lua_pushnumber(L, (lua_Number) sent);
```

where the variable `sent` was calculated just a few statements above (check `socket_sendto` call.

So, the returned `4` is exactly what [@moteus commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177726/what-does-unconnectedsendto-return-value-mean#comment63782492_38177726): **The number of bytes sent**.

Answer (score 1):

`sendto` returns the [number of bytes sent](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/src/udp.c#L201).